# Calculate memory size given address and its value

Tags: computer-architecture, memory-hardware

> Given the address 00011001111011101111101011011111 and it save a value
> 0x1FA0CBB7. Calculate the memory size in KB

**What i try**: the address has 32 bits so the memory size is 2^32 = 4294967296 bytes but then i wonder so the value 0x1FA0CBB7 for what ? I'm not sure i'm doing right.

Can someone help me solve this problem and explain why the question give value of address

Really appreciate your help.

Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to COMPUTER **SCIENCE** @SE. How do you know the addressable unit to be *byte*? Can you represent 0x1FA0CBB7 in one, say, [22-bit machine word](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word_(computer_architecture)#Table_of_word_sizes)?

Comment: i found that 0x1FA0CBB7 represent 32 bits (4 byte) so can we 2^32 * 4 ?

Comment: Without further context, I hold the question is impossible to answer correctly. What if that's a *virtual address* on a vintage computer? Even [main memory used to be costly](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/3M_computer).

Comment: it's not mentioned so i am confused right now